# phpStorm showing php syntax in just some .ctp files

Tags: php, syntax, phpstorm

I am using phpStorm a while, and now I am experiencing something that doesn't make sense.
I always used .ctp files as HTML and php syntax. And it work pretty fine.

But now, I've declared a function as "*between*", and phpStorm cannot help with any syntax in the between.ctp file.

I mean, if I rename the file to something like "_*between*", it works, and any other name the syntax works. Just this name doesn't, I do not have any idea of why.

Ok, probably a bug.
But I need to figure it out why, and resolve it. I need this function name to be "*between*"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you accidentally create a file without a file extension.

When you open such a file, PhpStorm will ask you as what format to treat the the file. This will cause it to create a new pattern for the file type and then it will always detect the file as that type.

1. Open the **Settings** and search for **File Types** to switch to the correct settings page.
2. Check the file types for one that has the pattern "between" and remove it.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you to remember this. But as I said, the file does have .ctp extension. If I just rename to anything else it works, but only "between.ctp" doens't.

Comment: @PatrickBard: So, did you check if you have a file type pattern for "between.ctp"?